# 2nd order Matrix differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, block-matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

$\ddot{X}+W\dot{X}=X$, $W$ is n-dimensional skew symmetric matrix. $X$ is a column vector and $I$ is identity matrix of appropriate dimension.

\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}
XX \\ \dot{X}
\end{array}\right)
=
e^{\left(\begin{array}
00 & I\\ I& -W
\end{array}\right)t}
\left(\begin{array}
XX(0)  \\ \dot{X}(0)
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}.

How do I simplify 
\begin{equation}
A
=
e^{\left(\begin{array}
00 & I\\ I& -W
\end{array}\right)t}
\end{equation}.
For example if euclidean $|W|=1$, Then $e^{Wt}=I+W*Sin(t)+W^2(1-Cos( t))$ (Rogrig's formulae). In the same way how can I simplify the above exponential. I tried doing it by diagonalizing it, but it didnt workout as $W$ is arbitrary. I don't need the complete solution, just point me where to read. I even tried to see if the series converges, but failed. Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1):

If $W$ is skew-symmetric, they $W=U^*(iD)U$, where $U^*U=I$ and $D$ diagonal, with real elements, and $iD$ has imaginary elements on the diagonal.

Then
$$
\ddot X+W\dot X-X=U^*(U\ddot X)+U*iD(U\dot X)-U^*UX=0,
$$
or for $Y=UX$
$$
\ddot Y+iD\dot Y-Y=0,
$$
Thus
$$
Y(t)=\mathrm{e}^{tL_1}Y_1+\mathrm{e}^{tL_2}Y_2,
$$
where
$$
L_{1,2}=-\frac{i}{2}D+\sqrt{I-\tfrac{1}{4}D^2}.
$$
Note that $L_{1,2}$ are readily definable as they are diagonal.

Comment: but how do i find the Uninary matrix U in terms of 'W'.

Comment: Isn't $U$ just full of the eigenvectors of $W$?

Comment: Yes, W can be any arbitrary skew symmetric matrix. So, writing a closed form (I think its called closed form) solution $X(t)=F(W)$, $X(t)$ as a function of $W$ is what I want (or something like rodrig formulae, see the question). I discarded this method because I don't know how to find eigen vectors for arbitarary skew-symmetric matrix. So, I tried doing by finding some closed form expression for the exponential series (ex: Rodrigs formulae). But I failed miserably.